# JS/JQ if/else user role check

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I can't seem to get my code to check which user role I've selected from the drop down. I don't often use  for this so I'm kind of running into some trouble with it I think. Let me know if I'm missing something? I left the console.log()'s in but they haven't returned anything.

```js
var userRole = "";
if ($('select[name=custom1]').find(':selected').val("") === "Healthcare Practitioner") {
  return userRole = "SR-Practitioner";
  console.log(userRole);
} else {
  return userRole = "SR-Educator";
  console.log(userRole);
};
```

Comment: Since you're passing an argument to `.val()`, it acts as a setter and your if condition can never be true... The downvote btw is because you can just find such information from the docs. I'm even surprised you found the second overload since the parameterless function is at the top.

Comment: a return statement is an exit point of a function. Everything after the return statement won't be executed. One exception is code that are wrapped in a try finally block.

Comment: Complementing what @MDeSchaepmeester rightfully said, when using `.val(arg)` the `jQuery Object` itself is returned, thus making the comparison to a string always yield `false`.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester Thanks. So remove the " " from .val() and it should snap into place or is my code just totally screwy?

Comment: @AlexMarple you also need to fix where the `return`s are. Your code doesn't seem to know what a `return` actually does.

Comment: using just `val()` will return the value of the selected element and also you need to re-arrange your `return` & `console` statements. Anything after `return` is not executed, so console first and return next. That would be spotted as an error in case you use an IDE :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A return statement is an exit point of a function. Everything after the return statement won't be executed. One exception is code that are wrapped in a try finally block. Therefore the console.log won't be executed.

Like @MDeSchaepmeester wrote: a .val(arg) call is a setter not a getter. Please read the documentation of .val(): http://api.jquery.com/val/

```js
if ($('select[name=custom1]').find(':selected').val() === "Healthcare Practitioner") {
  return "SR-Practitioner";
} else {
  return "SR-Educator";
};
```

or

```
var userRole = '';
if ($('select[name=custom1]').find(':selected').val() === "Healthcare Practitioner") {
  userRole = "SR-Practitioner";
} else {
  userRole "SR-Educator";
};

console.log(userRole);
```